# Experimental Sockets API in Google App Engine for SMTP connections

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sockets, smtplib

With the recent release of App Engine 1.7.7, it is finally possible to make outbound connections with TCP or UDP sockets. This opens a whole world of new possibilities.

Using `import socket` in Python 2.5, I have been able to test successfully a few simple low-level commands (such as socket.getaddrinfo("smtp.gmail.com", 587)...)

I am now trying to initiate an authenticated SMTP connection on port 587:

```
import smtplib
session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
```

... but I immediately encounter a `NotImplementedError` from the **gethostbyaddr** function in _remote_socket.py. This is surprising, as the non-implementation of this function is not mentioned in the Google App Engine Sockets API Overview at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/overview

Any idea what's going on here, and how I could circumvent this limitation?

**Note** : I have not yet migrated to Python 2.7. I am still using Python 2.5 and old_dev_appserver.py for the development server.

Thank you.

Comment: I have found quite different system api guards/whitelists between the old dev server and the new dev server.  My guess is the socket api isn't even supported on the old dev server.  Just a guess but I can't see why they would bother putting some of these experimental features in the old dev server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try passing in local_hostname to the constructor?

session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587, local_hostname='appengine.google.com')

Comment: It DID work. Thanks! There were however other issues with SSL, I guess that I'll have to upgrade to the new development server and Python 2.7 to really benefit from the Sockets API and smtplib.